# R- continued fraction

Tags: r, vectorization

Is it possible to create a function for continued fraction estimation in R, given a vector of numerics?

The formula is:

[image]

Comment: Try searching cran.r-project.org, I think there is at least one package devoted to continued fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define a recursive function `f` to calculate the contiuned fraction

```
f <- function(v) {
  ifelse(length(v) == 1, v, v[1] + 1 / f(v[-1]))
}
```

However, a drawback is that there is a limitation on the recursion depth, e.g.,

```
> f(1:1e5)
Error: node stack overflow
```

Thus, if you have a large array `v`, a better option might be using `for` loops, e.g.,

```
f <- function(v) {
  if (length(v) == 1) {
    return(v)
  }
  s <- tail(v, 1)
  for (k in (length(v) - 1):1) {
    s <- v[k] + 1 / s
  }
  s
}
```

and you will see

```
> f(1:1e5)
[1] 1.433127
```

Comment: Important to observe that, if you define your continued fraction in the format  `[a; b1,b2,b3,b4,...]` that you have to include the `a` in your input `x`  . Otherwise this function won't put your final `s` into a denominator.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes, you are right, thanks for feedback!

Answer (score 2):

Using recursion one option to achieve your desired result may look like so:

```r
cfrac <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  if (n > 1) {
    res <- x[1] + 1 / cfrac(x[2:n]) 
  } else {
    res <- x
  }
  return(res)
}

identical(cfrac(2), 2)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(cfrac(c(2, 3)), 2 + 1 / 3)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(cfrac(c(-3, 2, 18)), -3 + 1 / (2 + 1 / 18))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Tools going in both directions are in the package [contfrac](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/contfrac/contfrac.pdf)